# Service invoked via http spring controller takes substantially longer

Tags: java, spring, cron, spring-restcontroller

I have a spring service that is meant to run every day at specific times:

```
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class MyServiceScheduler {

  private final MyService myService;

  @Timed("my.service")
  @Scheduled(cron = "${my.service}")
  @SchedulerLock(name = "MyService_start")
  public void scheduledMyService(){
    myService.doTheJob(Constants.FORWARD_DAYS_TO_EXPORT_WEEK);
  }
```

This service takes about 6 minutes to complete. However, I also created a spring controller for me to invoke the exact same service on demand:

```
@RestController
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@RequestMapping("/myservice")
public class MyServiceController {

    private final MyService myService;

    @PatchMapping("onDemand")
    public void onDemandMyService() {
        myService.doTheJob(Constants.FORWARD_DAYS_TO_EXPORT_WEEK);
    }
```

The difference here is that the service takes about 6h if invoked via an http request to this endpoint. My question is what are the potential causes for this difference.

Thank you for your attention.

Comment: according to the code you supplied, there is no reason why it would behave differently. who is supplying MyService? it is a Spring managed service?

Comment: Yes it is a Spring service annotated with @Service

Answer (score 0):

I would not consider the SpringBoot as the possible cause in this case. Rather, take a closer look at the actual implementation of the MyService, if its speed could be related to the time of the day, free resources or amount of data to be processed.

You did not provide anything about MyService implementation. But either way, 6 minutes, let alone 6 hours is a very long time. It probably means some extensive I/O operations, database process or computation is done. Time required could depend on various conditions ...